# yii CdbCriteria nested join

Tags: join, yii, nested, criteria

I have trouble creating a CdbCriteria with nested join. Here's the code in model (sorry it's in Indonesian. Hopefully anyone can understand the query):

```
public function report() {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->alias = "p";
    $criteria->select = "p.tanggal_transaksi, 
        MONTH( p.tanggal_transaksi ) AS bulan, 
        p.kode, 
        p.kode_supplier, 
        s.nama, 
        d.kode_bahan_baku,
        b.nama_barang,
        d.jumlah_kg,
        d.jumlah_cones,
        d.harga_satuan,
        d.harga_satuan * d.jumlah_cones AS total,
        FLOOR(d.harga_satuan * d.jumlah_cones * p.ppn / 100) AS ppn,
        (d.harga_satuan * d.jumlah_cones) + FLOOR(d.harga_satuan * d.jumlah_cones * p.ppn / 100) AS total_akhir
    ";
    $criteria->join = "JOIN m_supplier s ON s.kode = p.kode_supplier
        RIGHT JOIN t_pembelian_detail d ON d.kode_pembelian = p.kode
        JOIN m_bahan_baku b ON b.kode = d.kode_bahan_baku
    ";
    $criteria->together = TRUE;

    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

The name of the model is **TPembelian** and here is the relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'supplier' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MSupplier', 'kode_supplier'),
        'tPembelianDetails' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TPembelianDetail', 'kode_pembelian'),
    );
}
```

In a controller, I wrote these lines of codes to just simply print out each attributes of CActiveDataProvider:

```
    $model = new TPembelian('search');
    $dataProvider = $model->report();
    foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $data) {
        echo "<pre>".print_r($data->attributes, 1)."</pre>";
    }
```

the problem is, it only prints out the attributes from TPembelian model (which use alias "p"). Why are other attributes (with other alias beside "p") not printed?

I have searched for a while and it appears that CActiveDataProvider not returning one long query, but instead it returns many query with HAS_MANY relation. Someone said to use "together" and set it to TRUE (I wrote it already in the code above) to make it returns one long query, but it's still not working. Can anybody please help me?

Note:
in the first code, m_supplier, t_pembelian_detail, and m_bahan_baku are **tables**, not models

Comment: Did you try using criteria->with to include the relations to the criteria? It can be nested.

Comment: I tried using "with", but the field of tables that are in the with doesn't appear too. Instead it returns error saying that, that field is not defined.

Comment: You have to reference them with the alias. Like for the main model you can use t. and for the fields with relations you can try supplier.field and tPembelianDetails.field etc ...